# how to add checked attr to a radio button nth-child with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

i have a group of radio buttons, and i want to add checked attr to one of them.
this is my code:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd1">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd2">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd3">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd4">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="rd5">

<script>
   $('input[name=slider]:nth-child(3)').prop('checked', true);
</script>
```

and i tested the script with .attr('checked', 'checked').
but the script not work true. whats my wrong?

Comment: try $('input[name=radioButton]:nth-child(3)').attr("checked","checked")

Comment: you have to change the name from slider to radioButton, for this to work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input[name=radioButton]:nth-child(3)').attr('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('input[name=radioButton]:nth-child(3)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

**Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/dxP4f/)**

Comment: Does not work with multiple button groups if they coexist in the same space: [jsfiddle/76pyq2ae](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/76pyq2ae/). This works if you grouo them in a list: [jsfiddle/Lrb46qL3](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/Lrb46qL3/).

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
$('input[name=radioButton]:eq(2)').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
   $('input[name=radioButton]:nth-child(3)').attr('checked', 'checked');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Use attr instead of prop.

```
 $('input[name=slider]:nth-child(3)').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="hello" id="rd1">
```

You could add a **value** attribute and use this:

$('input[name="radioButton"][**value**="hello"]').prop('checked', true);

Note: "nth-child" may cause issues in some browsers if you have multiple radio buttons before these with a different group.